Can a spider person i.e. Arachne, make themselves undetectable to smell?
So I am writing a story with a spider/human hybrid creature living in the attic. There is a dog, but it was questioned why the dog hadn't smelled the creature if the creature had been there for a while. Any thoughts?

Hi Roger, welcome to Worldbuilding. Per the [tour], Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum. It's purpose is to help you solve specific, reasonably objective and well-focused questions using as a model, "one-specific-question/one-best-answer." The easiest answer to your friend would be, "because the dog can't" but, "realistically" there's the problem of food, waste, etc. which causes odor regardless of physiology. Thus, your question would benefit from being focused on a single, specific issue. Can you do that? Thanks.

BTW, it would help if you read [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask] so you understood the limitations of this service. Open-ended brainstorming is not us.

There could be any number of reasons... perhaps the dog is just too lazy to care, perhaps the creature had always been there and the dog didn't know any different.  Perhaps the creature was nice to the dog.  Not having an odour seems very unlikely.  However, this question is at risk of being closed  for lack of specificity and details, amongst other things.

The thing about lofts is that hot air goes up (assuming the house is permanently occupied). Any aroma in the loft is likely to disappear into the neighborhood before it bothers the people downstairs - excepting for the occasional freak gust giving them a whiff.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Perhaps spider-people could just smell like a mixture of spiders and people, and as both scents are common in the house the dog doesn't realize anything is amiss

nothing that breathes can be completely undetectable to smell.

I think the question is a valid one because it asks for specific answer: why doesn't the dog smell the spider-person in the attic? There is a potential answer: that convection moves air upwards. Only the final 'any thoughts?' suggests brainstorming, but that may be just a polite coda to the post.

Are we talking about a approx. 2m tall creature with a large spider body and a human torso, around 100kg+ in weight? Or are we talking about a 2cm creature with a normal spider body but they have the ability to use their feet like "human hands" and can "speak"? Please elaborate on the size and type of hybrid form.

A large spider body and a human torso. Roughly 5'7" tall and 210 lbs.

Firstly if the creature was already present in the home before the dog was introduced? Unless there is a confrontation between them then as far as the dog is concerned the scent of your creature is just part of the normal background odor stream in the house.
Secondly warm air tends to rise taking scents with it. So anything stored (or living) in the attic with a distinct odor is probably not going to be noticed by a dog on the lower floors unless for some reason it enters the attic space itself - which lets face it is rather unlikely.
Thirdly if the creature is a careful about disposing of it's bodily wastes or the remains of it's prey outside of the house there won't be any leakage of fluids into the floors below.
However you have a far BIGGER problem than scent unfortunately. (Noise!) Most dogs have a far more acute sense of hearing than humans do. So given enough time any large creature living in the roof space is almost certainly going to be detected by the dog unless (A) there's something wrong with this particular animals ears or (b) your creature has preternatural stealth.

I have zero experience of spider-people, but spiders are very good at detecting tremors in webs, and are also capable of staying completely still for long periods. It may be that the spider-person is more aware of the dog than the other way around.

@Richard Kirk The creature may well be away of the dog (and the family that owns it of course) the problems remains when IT decides to move. When staying still there's no problem but a man sized (massed) object moving about in your average attic is going to make nose unless it moves very carefully and slowly albeit 'spider man' having multiple limbs should have a distinct advantage when it comes to moving around quietly.

Well most spiders can move around stealthily. So I am using that assumption for a spider human hybrid.

Most spiders move around stealthily AND do not have a body weight of 210lbs. It's a definite engineering challenge to reconcile those requirements.
